# SQL - Too many calls to subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

The below query is fairly slow, in terms of the subquery selection for the "skill name". When I run a profile against the SQL execution I am getting far too many queries per line from the ACDCallinformation table against the sub query for skillname.

What is the best way of optimising this SQL query or is there a MySQL tool to help with checking on costs for a SQL query and optimising the script?

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN(
            SELECT 
                COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)
            FROM acdcallinformation ag
            WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
        ) IS NULL 
    THEN 
            0 
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)
                FROM acdcallinformation ag
            WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL AND DATEofcall= DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid) 
        END AS 'Lost Calls', 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) END AS 'Total Calls', 
        CASE WHEN COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) END AS 'Answered',
    (
        SELECT 
            skillinfo.skillname
        FROM skillinfo
        WHERE skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid
    ) AS Skill, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation
WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY skill;
```

Not sure the best way show data:

ACDCALLINFORMATION - number of rows currently 3028

```
INSTIME              PKEY   DATEOFCALL  CONNECTTIME FIRSTRING SKILLID
2012-07-19 14:50:16  19985  2012-07-19  14:50:16    14:50:16  5
```

SKILLINFO - Average number of rows is 5-10

```
INSTIME              PKEY   SKILLNAME
2012-07-01 13:12:01  1      Calls Outgoing
2012-07-01 13:12:01  2      Call Centre
2012-07-01 13:12:01  3      Accounts
2012-07-01 13:12:01  4      Reception
```

This is the output expected:

```
"Lost Calls"    "Total Calls"   "Answered"  "Skill"         "Average Answer Time" "Average Talk Time"

"1"         "2"          "1"            "Accounts"  "00:00:04"  "00:00:01"
"0"         "5"          "5"            "Service"   "00:00:07"  "00:01:20"
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Can you post tables structures , sample data and desired output. We might be able to present some optimized query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, is using inner joins to improve performance and avoid unnecessary subquerys

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(ag.skillcount, 0) AS 'Lost Calls', 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) END AS 'Total Calls', 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) END AS 'Answered',
    si.skillname AS Skill, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT skillid,  COUNT(`PKEY`) - COUNT(`ANSWERTIME`) skillcount
    FROM acdcallinformation 
    WHERE (`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW())
) ag ON  AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
LEFT JOIN skillinfo si ON si.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid
WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY si.skillname;
```

Comment: +1 for offering a `JOIN` alternative. Mind though that inline subqueries are equivalent to (`LEFT`) outer joins, not inner ones. You may lose some data with this query.

Comment: And that `CASE WHEN ag.skillcount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ag.skillcount END` can be written as `COALESCE(ag.skillcount, 0)`

Comment: Perfect thanks.. seems to be much better than before. I need to read up on optimising my queries, what to avoid etc.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to ensure that `NULL`s are converted to `0`s. Thus:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(
    (SELECT COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`) FROM acdcallinformation ag
       WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL 
        AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
    ), 0)  AS 'Lost Calls', 
    IFNULL(COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue), 0) AS 'Total Calls', 
    IFNULL(COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`),0) AS 'Answered',
    (
        SELECT 
            skillinfo.skillname
        FROM skillinfo
        WHERE skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid
    ) AS Skill, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation
WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY skill;
```

Although, it might be easier to just convert  those `NULL`s to zeros using the language that consumes this data... just a thought.

Also, my reading of the docs for [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) make me think that it will never return `NULL`, thus:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`) FROM acdcallinformation ag
       WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL 
        AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
  )  AS 'Lost Calls', 
  COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) AS 'Total Calls', 
  COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) AS 'Answered',
    (
        SELECT 
            skillinfo.skillname
        FROM skillinfo
        WHERE skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid
    ) AS Skill, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation
WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY skill;
```

Finally, I think you can handle your second query with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT 
      IFNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`) FROM acdcallinformation ag
           WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL 
            AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
        ), 0)  AS 'Lost Calls', 
        IFNULL(COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue), 0) AS 'Total Calls', 
        IFNULL(COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`),0) AS 'Answered',
        skillinfo.skillname AS Skill, 
        SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
        SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
    FROM `acdcallinformation` acdcallinformation 
       INNER JOIN skillinfo ON skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid 
    WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
    GROUP BY skill;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. The whole query is just a guess but it would be batter if you provided some data. Also i have used id as primary key you need to replace it with your own key. Avoid using subqueries instead use joins they are much faster. Here is the query.

```
SELECT 
    IF(l.LDifference IS NULL,0,r.RDifference) AS 'Lost Calls', 
    IF(COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue) IS NULL , 0 , COUNT(acdcallinformation.idleonqueue))AS 'Total Calls', 
    IF(COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`) IS NULL,0,COUNT(acdcallinformation.`ANSWERTIME`))AS 'Answered',
    (SELECT skillinfo.skillname FROM skillinfo  WHERE skillinfo.pkey = acdcallinformation.skillid) AS Skill, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(a.answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(a.firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(a.IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(a.answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM acdcallinformation as a
INNER JOIN( 
    SELECT  
        (COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)) as `LDifference`
    FROM acdcallinformation ag
    WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid  
) as l ON l.id = a.id
INNER JOIN( 
    SELECT (COUNT(ag.`PKEY`) - COUNT(ag.`ANSWERTIME`)) as `RDifference`
        FROM acdcallinformation ag
    WHERE (ag.`COMPLETED`) = 1 AND answertime IS NULL AND DATEofcall= DATE(NOW()) AND ag.skillid = acdcallinformation.skillid
) as r ON r.id = a.id   
WHERE a.DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY skill;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This.
Use INNER JOIN, IF() and try to avoid unnecessary subqueries.

```
SELECT IFNULL(ag.skillcount, 0) AS 'Lost Calls', COUNT(info.idleonqueue) AS 'Total Calls', 
         COUNT(info.ANSWERTIME) AS 'Answered', si.skillname AS Skill, 
         SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(answertime)- TIME_TO_SEC(firstringonqueue))) AS 'Average Answer Time', 
         SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(IDLEONQUEUE) - TIME_TO_SEC(answertime))) AS 'Average Talk Time'
FROM acdcallinformation AS info
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT skillid, COUNT(PKEY)-COUNT(ANSWERTIME) skillcount
            FROM acdcallinformation 
            WHERE COMPLETED = 1 AND DATEofcall = DATE(NOW()) AND answertime IS NULL 
           ) ag ON ag.skillid = info.skillid
INNER JOIN skillinfo si ON si.pkey = info.skillid
WHERE DATEOFCALL = DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY si.skillname;
```